# what is best approach to implement real time notifications using node.js and MySql

Tags: mysql, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to implement real time notification system, the approach that i am going to use is by opening a different socket using node's socket.io module, and then record each event of a user, afterwards send data to Mysql and use this data for notifications. So is it a better approach, any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would go for redis+node. Main reason is to lower disk IO. Negative side might be possible data loss with redis (server reboot, service restart etc.). But that also can be [configured](http://redis.io/topics/persistence) in redis.